Two definitions of Borwein integrals: same numerators?
This is a boring question on a very interesting subject.
The usual definition of the $n$th Borwein integral is
$$ I_n = \int_\limits0^\infty \prod\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{\sin(x/(2k+1))}{x/(2k+1)} \, dx. $$
It is known that $C_n=I_n\left/\frac{\pi}{2}\right.$ is always a rational number: $C_0=1,C_1=1,C_2=1,$ and so on. Wikipedia (link above) provides a nice combinatorial formula for $C_n$, found by Borwein, Borwein, and so on.
Another definition used exclusively by MathWorld is (using the index $n$ which agrees with the formula for $I_n$ above but not with MathWorld):
$$ W_n = \frac1\pi\int_\limits0^\infty x^{-(n+1)} \prod\limits_{k=0}^n \sin\left(\frac{x}{2k+1}\right) \, dx. $$
We have $W_0=1/2,W_1=1/6\ldots$, and in general
$$ W_n = \frac{C_n/2}{(2n+1)!!}. $$
My question is: do $W_n$ and $C_n$, written as reduced fractions, always have the same numerator?
If no, what about $C_n/2=I_n/\pi$ — does it share the numerator with $C_n$ or $W_n$?
